# How to get some spesific string from a NSString?

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring

Hello I have a NSString like this

```
 #EXTM3U
 #EXT-X-VERSION:3
 #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
 #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
 #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2933
 #EXTINF:10.031,
 media_w687716935_2933.mp3
 #EXTINF:10.031,
 media_w687716935_2934.mp3
 #EXTINF:10.031,
 media_w687716935_2935.mp3
```

from this string I want to get all the .mp3 files. How can I do that? Please help me.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I put like this

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex2 = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\w+(?=\\.mp3)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

[regex2 enumerateMatchesInString:strM3u81 options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [strM3u81 length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
}
```

but here  the inside code of the block not excecute. Whats the wrong with that? and how can I get those file names?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yeas I will update the question

Comment: Why duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118755/how-extract-something-from-nsstring

Answer (score 1):

```
\S+\.mp3
```

Try this.See demo  .

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/21

Comment: how can I give this regular expression in ios?

Comment: because still it skip the block

Comment: @user2889249 why will it skip the block

Comment: I think it skips because it doesnt take the regular expression exactly

Comment: @user2889249 are you providing the input line by line?You can pass it one go

Comment: Im doing like this   strM3u81=[M3U8Parser m3u8tringFromData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlm3u82]]; this string is that above posted output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good in regular expression so I do it in another way.
Try this code

```
   NSString *input = @"#EXTM3U\n #EXT-X-VERSION:3\n #EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11\n #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:2933\n #EXTINF:10.031,\n media_w687716935_2933.mp3\n #EXTINF:10.031,\n media_w687716935_2934.mp3\n #EXTINF:10.031,\n media_w687716935_2935.mp3";
   NSArray *subBreakingLineStrings = [input componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *subString in subBreakingLineStrings) {
        if ([subString rangeOfString:@".mp3"].location != NSNotFound) {
            [results addObject:subString];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"result = %@", results);
```

output:

```
result = (
    " media_w687716935_2933.mp3",
    " media_w687716935_2934.mp3",
    " media_w687716935_2935.mp3"
)
```

Comment: .mp3 file are changing time to time,, so cannot be hard coded